# Where should _uihooks be defined

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

The only documentation I can find about the _uihooks added in meteor 0.8.2 is in the [transition-helper project](https://github.com/percolatestudio/transition-helper/blob/master/transition-helper.js#L4). Which defines the _uihooks in the rendered event.

If I define the _uihooks in the rendered hook the insertElement _uihook is pretty useless. Because the first time it runs _uihooks doesn't exist yet, so the first item doesn't get animated.

Ofcourse I could just put my insertElement animation in the rendered hook itself, but why then does insertElement even exist?

So is there a different place I should define the _uihooks? Or should I just ignore the insertElement hook for now?

Comment: Have you tried the `Template.name.created` callback? That might work better.

Comment: @user3374348 In the created hook there is to my knowledge no reference to the parentnode of the template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `_uihooks` should be defined on the immediate parent element that is enclosing the `{{#each}}` helper, and this is ideally done in its `.rendered` callback.

Here's an how I do it in my app:

> https://github.com/mizzao/CrowdMapper/blob/master/client/views/datastream.coffee

Comment: So how do I use something from the data of the child template then?
Like I tried to achieve here on r20: https://github.com/gfk-ba/meteor-notifications/blob/master/notification.js

Comment: The app now uses a package, which is here: https://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/animated-each

Comment: @Marco: Note that `UI` is no longer available as of Meteor 1.0.3.1. You might want to use [`Blaze.getData()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze_getdata).